# how to group by week start from friday

Tags: mysql

I have table sql like this:

[image: column id and tanggal is primary key]

This my query for count tgl:

```
SELECT count( tgl ) AS total, absen.id
FROM absen
WHERE absen.status = 'm'
GROUP BY absen.id
```

So I want group by absen.id and absen.tgl
How to group by week from Friday to Thursday?
2016-01-08 is friday and 2016-01-15 is thursday.

Comment: you want to group by current week (week that start from friday) specific days interval?

Comment: No,  I want group by week not only current week but last week, next week ...
I want to group by week starting from Friday until Thursday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow query can bring the result you want, but i think you defined the wrong end date, because in your example from 2015-01-08 up to 2015-01-15 its 8 day and one week has 7 days.

```
select
   count( tgl ) AS total, 
   absen.id,
   CASE WHEN (weekday(tgl)<=3) THEN date(tgl + INTERVAL (3-weekday(tgl)) DAY)
    ELSE date(tgl + INTERVAL (3+7-weekday(tgl)) DAY)
   END as week_days
FROM absen
WHERE status = 'm'
GROUP BY id,week_days
```

here is the fiddle [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e76599/13)

Query Description:
mysql weekday array numbers:

```
$weekArr = array(
        'Monday' => 0,
        'Tuesday' => 1,
        'Wednesday' => 2,
        'Thursday' => 3,
        'Friday' => 4,
        'Saturday' => 5,
        'Sunday' => 6);
```

So now suppose today is Tuesday and date is 2016-01-12, now let's count from today towards the start date in our table which is 2016-01-07 and it match with Thursday of past week, so according to the weekday array number its `weekday(2016-01-07) == 3` so it goes to the `WHEN` part of our query, and query will select something like this `CASE WHEN (weekday('2016-01-07') <= 3) THEN date('2016-01-07' + INTERVAL(3-3))` that is equal to `SELECT '2016-01-07'` and so on for others.

Comment: LOl, I have wrong end date buut thanks sir this work
can you explain about this query (weekday(tgl)<=3) THEN date(tgl + INTERVAL (3-weekday(tgl)) DAY)
    ELSE date(tgl + INTERVAL (3+7-weekday(tgl)) DAY)

Comment: @faza I have described now the query, hope to be clear enough, but if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to get this by trouble shooting on excel by using this WEEK('date' + INTERVAL 3 DAY, 3)